# Passing scope variable to a popover template angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popover

I have a table which has a popover hover on each row, and on each row, the popover content should have different content. I made a popover template like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
    <td>{{ x.id  }}</td>
   <td>
       <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
         This is the content of the template: {{ x.id  }}
        </script>
        <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon custom-glyph glyphicon-zoom-in" mypopover data-placement="right" ></span> </a>
   </td>             
</tr>
```

My JS

```
app.directive('mypopover', function ($compile,$templateCache) {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var popOverContent = $templateCache.get("templateId.html");
        var options = {
            content: popOverContent,
            placement: "right",
            html: true,
                        trigger: 'hover'
        };
        $(element).popover(options);
    }
};
});
```

But when I viewed to the browser the output is: `This is the content of the template: {{ x.id  }}`

The `{{x.id}}` is being interpreted inside the `<script>` tag? I am also new to angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use 'uib-popover-html' structure directive instead of the 'mypopover' you made?

Download and declare dependency 'uib-bootstrap'.

Then templateId.html will know the variable x

Here is the doc https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/